# How to digitally sign PDF document using iTextSharp with PKCS7 standard (.cer)

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature

I have tried to sign the PDF document using .pfx file and it signed properly. but i need to know how to sign the PDF document using .cer file. please advise me in this, it will be helpful if there is any sample or documentation regarding this.

Note: using C# for implementation

Comment: Can you show us what you've achieved already? Are you getting stuck somewhere? Did you have a look at http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-3 (source links fro C# appear to broken right now, people have been made aware, but the code is similar to java), did you read the white paper  (http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-digital-signatures-for-pdf.html)?

Comment: A `.cer` file is a file that you share with other people. It contains your public key and information about who you are. A `.pfx` file is a file that contains cryptographic information such as your private key. You say that you can sign a document using a `.pfx` file, and that is correct, because **you need a private key to sign.** You say that you want to sign a document using a `.cer` file, but that is kind of absurd because a `.cer` file is public. It doesn't contain a private key, does it? Without a private key, how are you going to sign a document?

Comment: Also: when you use a `.pfx` file, you use the PKCS#12 standard. An alternative is to sign using PKCS#11 in which case the private key isn't stored in a file but on a device (from which the private key can't be extracted). You mention PKCS#7, but that's just the CMS standard. You can create a PKCS#7 signature using a `.pfx` file. I think you are confusing PKCS standards: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS